# Find and Replace multiple digits with the last character in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, digits, find-replace

Does anyone know how to replace several different Digits all at once in notepad++.

**For example**, I have 4 different Digits;

```
1000x1000.jpg
750x750.jpg
1000x750.jpg
750x1000.jpg
```

**I want the result like this:**

```
1000x1000.jpg 1000
650x550.jpg 650
1200x850.jpg 1200
350x1300.jpg 350
```

I was trying to select each first digit and make them in groups with this Regex:

```
([0-9]{4}x+[0-9]{4}.jpg)|([0-9]{3}x+[0-9]{4}.jpg)|([0-9]{3}x+[0-9]{3}.jpg)|([0-9]{4}x+[0-9]{3}.jpg)
```

But I can't replace them after `.jpg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^(\d+)x\d+\.jpg$
```

Replace with `$0 $1`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OyP6iF/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 (`$1`): one or more digits
- `x` - an `x` char
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\.jpg`  - a `.jpg` string
- `$` - end of string (line here, in Notepad++).

Note that `$0` is a backreference to the whole match value. `$1` refers to Group 1 value.

**Regex variations**

If the match does not fit the whole line, use either word (`\b(\d+)x\d+\.jpg\b`) or numeric/word (`(?<!\d)(\d+)x\d+\.jpg\b`) boundaries.

See demo:

[image]

Comment: thank you, Mr.Wiktor,
is there any solution to applicate (^(\d+)x\d+\.jpg$) in notepad++

https://i.ibb.co/tPm1gX7/Capture.jpg

because i have a big data to replace

Comment: @EnigmaOs Fill the `Replace With` text box with `$0 $1`.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add humbly previously posted code. Because just added "concat" function and simple code.

```
 select col,concat(col,regexp_replace(col,'^(\d+)x(\d+)\.jpg','\1')) as c from 
(   select '1000x1000.jpg ' as col from dual union all
    select '650x550.jpg ' as col from dual union all
    select '1200x850.jpg ' as col from dual union all
    select '350x1300.jpg ' as col from dual
)
```